# Decrease space between activities in Rehosted Workflow Designer

Tags: workflow-foundation

Using WF 4 we have made a prototype of a tool, which will be used for writing test cases. The test cases might be huge, more than 1000 activities. And we received complaint that test cases become hard to read due to a lot of unused space. 
Is it possible to remove/decrease these useless arrows between activities?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have figured out myself. 
WorkflowItemsPresenter.SpacerTemplate should be used.